# ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _chkLogin(userid varchar, pwd varchar)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 passed BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
 SELECT  (_password = $2) FROM _vRegistration WHERE _userid = $1;
 RETURN passed;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

When am executing the code above am getting the following error,

```
SELECT _chkLogin('username','abcd') as passed;
```

> ERROR: query has no destination for
>   result data

I've used perform then i get a different problem,

```
PERFORM _chkLogin('username','abcd');
```

> ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "perform"

Suggest me what should I be doing in order to overcome this error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You do return passed but you *never* assign value to it.

And select command within the function has to have place to put data to.

So. Change your SQL to:

```
SELECT  (_password = $2) INTO passed FROM _vRegistration WHERE _userid = $1;
```

Also - since you're using names for variables (userid, pwd) **use them**:

```
SELECT  (_password = pwd) INTO passed FROM _vRegistration WHERE _userid = userid;
```

Answer (score 4):

### Notes about assign value

(see [this other question for assign value to variable at declaration section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21932493/287948))

The language PLpgSQL syntax have many ways to say:

```
 Y := f(X);
```

The `EXECUTE` clause is only for "dynamic execution" (*less performance*),

```
 EXECUTE 'f(X)' INTO Y;
```

Use `Y := f(X);` or `SELECT` for execute static declarations,

```
 SELECT f(X) INTO Y;
```

Use [PERFORM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html) statment when discard the results or to work with void returns:

```
 PERFORM f(X);
```