# How to assign selected values from a table to specific variables in Pl/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, variable-assignment, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

For example, here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT name, address INTO variable1, variable2
         FROM employee WHERE id=1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Better alternative

Actually, there is nothing indicating a need for dynamic SQL. All identifiers are stable. Assuming you only want to parameterize the `id` value, simplify to:

```
SELECT name,address from employee where id = $1
INTO   variable1, variable2
```

Or:

```
SELECT INTO variable1, variable2
            e.name,    e.address
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.id = _my_variable;
```

The appropriate chapter in the manual: ["Executing a Query with a Single-row Result"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Dynamic SQL would be indicated when working with parameterized table or column names.
[Here is a list of related question for *dynamic SQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql+plpgsql)

#### Cause for immediate problem

The reason why your original code did not work, [per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> `SELECT INTO` is not currently supported within `EXECUTE`; instead,
>   execute a plain `SELECT` command and specify `INTO` as part of the
>   `EXECUTE` itself.

[@a_horse demonstrates valid syntax in his answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21987185/939860)

Either alternative relies on the query to return a *single* row. If your id is defined unique, that cannot break.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT name,address from employee where id=1'
   INTO variable1, variable2;
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Better to also use a parameter instead of concatenated values (to prevent SQL injection):

```
l_emp_id := 1;
EXECUTE 'SELECT name,address from employee where id=$1'
   INTO variable1, variable2
   USING l_emp_id;
```

Comment: Great! Finally working, Thank you so much a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 0):

### Assign value, general note

(see [this other question for assign value to variable at declaration section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21932493/287948))

The language PLpgSQL syntax have many ways to say:

```
 Y := f(X);
```

The `EXECUTE` clause is only for "dynamic execution" (*less performance*),

```
 EXECUTE 'f(X)' INTO Y;
```

Use `Y := f(X);` or `SELECT` for execute static declarations,

```
 SELECT f(X) INTO Y;
```

Use [PERFORM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html) statment when discard the results or to work with void returns:

```
 PERFORM f(X);
```

Comment: ops, sorry and tanks! Edited!